# Shipment create not working programmatically

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, programmatically, shipment, create

I am using below code to create shipment programmatically.

```
$shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment($qty);
$shipment->register();
$shipment->sendEmail(true)->setEmailSent(true)->save();
```

But nothing is happening. No shipment is created in back-end and no error is reported.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your `$qty` and `$order` are correct. I don't think shipments can be created just doing a `save()`. Try this.

```
$shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)
    ->prepareShipment($qty);
$shipment->register();

$shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
    ->addObject($shipment)
    ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
    ->save();
```

See `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_ShipmentController::_saveShipment` for the exact implementation details.